# POST with an ID and GET the nested object does not work in django at the same time in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have spent already a couple of days researching about this issue in similar questions and I am not able to get a solution. This should be something simple, I have a model:

`model.py`

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    """Class to represent an item..."""

    label = models.TextField(null=True)
    name = models.TextField()

    category = models.ForeignKey(   "Category", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                    null=True, default=DEFAULT_CATEGORY_ID)

class Category(models.Model):
    """Class to represent the category of an Item. Like plants, bikes..."""
    name = models.TextField()

    description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

`view.py`

```py
class ItemViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet): # pylint: disable=too-many-ancestors
    """API Endpoint to return the list of items"""
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

`serializer.py`

```py
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Item."""

    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """Class to represent metadata of the object."""
        model = Item
        fields = [  'id', 'label', 'name', 'category']   
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        
        # def to_representation(self, instance):
        #     ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        #     ret['category'] = CategorySerializer(instance.category).data
        #     return ret
        def create(self, request):
            # Look up objects by arbitrary attributes.
            # You can check here if your students are participating
            # the classes and have taken the subjects they sign up for.
            category = get_object_or_404(Category(), id=request.data.get('category'))

            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save(category=category)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

If I have the line `category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)` commented the nested get won't work, for example for a curl to an object. I will get just de id of the structure. If I uncomment it like it is in the example I get the right response:

```json
{
  "id": 60,
  "label": null,
  "name": "Delete me",
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "IT"
  }
}
```

But then the post with id will not work, the category will be set to null.

How can I get both working at the same time?

Update: This is the post I want to do:

```json
{
    "label": "00000003",
    "name": "Delete me",
    "category": 1,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `to_represention` method of your serializer

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer for Item."""

    class Meta: # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """Class to represent metadata of the object."""
        model = Item
        fields = [  'id', 'label', 'name', 'category']   
        read_only_fields = ['id']
        
    def to_representation(self, instance):
            data = super().to_representation(instance)
            data["category"] = CategorySerializer(instance.category).data
            return data
```

Comment: I think that is exactly what I have commented in my Meta class, but then again, the POST works with ID, but the GET will not return the category structure.

Comment: I am afraid, but not exactly. the  line `category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)` in your code made the category as read_only attribute of the serializer. This means that the serializer was not taking category into consideration while creating the instance. here I had simply override the response I get after the instance is created to have the required format. Hope this answers your question. in case it doesn't let me know I shall try my best to explain further :)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have commented out that line, but still. When I post it saves the value corectly, but when I get the response of the created item I still get `category: 1` instead of `category: {id: 1...}`, and also when I request the list of items with GET it comes with the category as just the ID

Comment: ah. I am not sure, but can you try removing the `.data` from CategorySerializer like `          data["category"] = CategorySerializer(instance.category)`. Let me know if that helps

Comment: I just tried, but unfortunatley made no difference. Still the same, the GET is returned as the id integer instead of the data structure.

Comment: After some more hours getting desperate with this I found the problem. The answer is correct, but I was writing the method inside the class `Meta` and the `to_representation` actually belongs to the `ItemSerializer`. This issue can be seen in the question and the correct answer is here.

Comment: Another comment, the `.data` that you deleted in your edit is needed, as otherwise I get `Object of type CategorySerializer is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Thanks for updates ☺️.I will update the answer again.